# Code parser for own DSL in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, dsl

I'm looking for something like flex/bison that works with C# code. I want to be able to provide some language descriptors and a parser should be generated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dsl

Comment: John, I'm getting a "no wiki summary page" for that link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the goto methodolgy of building out a parser in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009111/whats-the-goto-methodolgy-of-building-out-a-parser-in-net)

Comment: @chris: and did you also get a list of 249 questions?

Comment: Maybe even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing

Comment: Ahh, I was stuck on "Featured"!

Answer (score 3):

There are several options.  I've found Irony to be good.  It's powerful, and it has a novel syntax utilizing C# operator overloads to convey the syntax of your grammars directly in C#.

Irony - .NET Language Implementation Kit.
http://irony.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Irony, hadn;t heard of it and from my first impressions I really like it.

Answer (score 2):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is a very common parser generator with output bindings for many languages (including c#), but it is LLR which might make it a little more cumbersome than flex/bison if that's what you are accustomed to.

Answer (score 1):

I've had my best luck with ANTLR, it can generate C# code as well. Good Language design support as well with ANTLR Works, an IDE for designing and testing your grammars, and quite a few tutorials to explain the whole thing.

Other option is the F# powerpack that has fsLex and fsYacc. Only brielfy poked at it, seems powerful but very little documentation.

For C# that's the two first thing to look at i think.

GJ