# Using Irony for custom language design in .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, language-design, irony

Just as the question says, I'm stuck with .Net 2.0 here in my company and there is no chance of upgrading. Is there a way to make Irony work in .NET 2.0.

I'll briefly try to explain what I'm trying to achieve. We at our company have a payroll system where we let customer define there own formulas for payslip items. These formulas must use some keywords/functions which we check through Regex(very unreliable). Then we create a Microsoft script control object and use its eval function to parse the snippet. These snippets in turn call keywords/functions defined in class to get the output.

But to say this system has drawback is being very polite. Sometimes the it just overflows with error.

A very silly e.g. -

```
FVAL(A)/(FVAL(B)+FVAL(C))
```

Obviously there the tow stages this formula passes through.

First the validation stage where we do the following -

- Check through regex whether there are any keywords used which are not present in  predefined arrayList of keywords
- Then check whether there are any variables(in this case - A, B, C are the ones) used which are not present in an arraylist of variable.
- If all validation passes then we pass the formula string to a ScriptControlClass object's eval function and also add a static class with all functions defined in it(in this case consider `FVAL()`) and this function returns boolean `true` if the variable is a valid one to use in this context(like adding a date and number would return false)

Now after evaluating this expression the result is - **DivideByZeroException**, why because eval typecasts all boolean `true` to `1` and performs normal arithmetic to it.

```
FVAL(A)/(FVAL(B)+FVAL(C)) => 1/(1-1)
```

The second phase is almost similar but without any validation check, like without returning true we actually return the value of the variable from a `DataTable` which consists of values for each variables.

The system is antiquated and its seriously getting on my nerves and I really need help. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just talking about excel style formulas, it's pretty easy to write a good interpreter, especially if you only have to deal with one data type. Someone with a background in compilers (or even parsers) could probably write you up on in less than a day. I've written a bunch myself.

[Embedding a scripting language](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/) is another option, but you'd have to be comfortable with the quirks of the given language. Ensuring that high-precision numbers are used could be difficult, if that's a business requirement.

Comment: What do you think of [Spart](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5676/Spart-a-parser-generator-framework-100-C#). Could you guide me to use Spart for my purpose. I think its enough for my needs. I'm just stuck without a "Getting Started" article.

Comment: There are [a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060583/code-parser-for-own-dsl-in-c-sharp) of options, but none of the compilers or interpreters I've implemented used any of them. Irony and Spart could both be great. Personally, I've written enough that I'd spend less time doing a simple grammar from scratch with a recursive descent system than learning an API.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a grammar using the code I posted in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the time - a fully correct implementation with proper diagnostic support and parsing messages would take several hours. If you want to hire me, [email me](http://nathanaeljones.com).